# Change content of a <Select> based on external input

Tags: jquery, select, symfony

Suppose you have two select type as shown in the picture, My question is how I can change the content of the select type based on the input from the first one.

[image]

Comment: there are 2 ways php with page refresh, ajax without page refresh

Comment: Yeah, you are completely right, perhaps jquery

Comment: WHY the down votes??

Answer (score 0):

simply call ajax method on **onchange()** method of the select/input control and load the data to another without page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am considering #partFamily and #FamilyType ids for two select elements

Try below jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#partFamily").on("change",function(){
    if($("#partFamily").val() != '')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "your url",
            data: { partFamilyId: $("#partFamily").val() },
            method: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#FamilyType").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $.each(data, function (i, value) {
                    $("#FamilyType").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(value.Id).html(value.Name));
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
       $("#FamilyType").html("");
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Jquery Library `Chained Selects`

https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

You will need to load all the choices in the second Select, and it will be filtered from the choice you make in the first one (no requests are made to the server)